# creating/ adding child to a child firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating/adding another child to a child with push ID

```
 var b = firebase.database().ref().child('User').push().key;
           var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

        if (user != null) {
          name = user.displayName;
          email = user.email;
          photoUrl = user.photoURL;
          emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
          uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                           // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                           // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
        }
        var data ={
            b {
             add: "one",
            nue: "21"
            }
        }
       var updates ={};

        updates['/User/' + uid] = data;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

[image]

I'm using the codes above but it gives an error because of

```
b {
     add: "one",
     nue: "21"
 }
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't know firebase, but if this is supposed to be json, you're missing a `:`.

Comment: how to add another child to the current child that will be looked like to the picture above, I used to add "b", I thought that it will display the push id that can store another value

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax error in your code. As gpgekko commented, you need a `:` after `b`:

```
    var data ={
        b: { // added a : on this line
            add: "one",
            nue: "21"
        }
    }
```

This makes your JavaScript structure syntactically valid.

But I'm guessing it's not what you want, since now `b` is a literal where I expect you want the value of `b` to become a key in the object. To accomplish that, you need to use square-bracket notation:

```
    var data = {};
    data[b] = {
        add: "one",
        nue: "21"
    };
```